# Extract the feature vectors

Tags: java, vector

to get the feature vector from csv file ,,

I have made a code to read my data sheet into eclipse with the help of a teacher assistant I reached to this code .. here is my code for reading the data and getting the feature vector., but i am getting exception which is (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Illegal embedded sign character) ... Here is a sample of what is the input and the output supposed to be:

[image: Desired input/output]

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "D:\\projcet\\data.csv";

        //BigInteger a =BigInteger.ZERO;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

            line =br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] a = line.split(cvsSplitBy);


                System.out.println("\""+a[0] + "\"," +"\""+a[1] + "\","+"\""+a[2] + "\","+"\""+a[3] + "\","+"\""+a[4] + "\","+"\""+a[5] + "\","+"\""+a[6] + "\","+"\""+a[7] + "\","
                        +"{" + "" + new BigInteger(a[1].trim()).bitCount() + "," 
                        + new BigInteger(a[4].trim()).bitCount() + ","
                        + new BigInteger(a[5].trim()).bitCount() + ","
                        + new BigInteger(a[6].trim()).bitCount() + ","
                        + new BigInteger(a[7].trim()).bitCount() + ".....}");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                     

}
```

Comment: What is a feature vector in your context?

Comment: the teacher didn't mention anything ,, in fact i posted same picture he sent me.@ Nico Schertler

Comment: Then consult your lecture notes or whatever material you have. If you don't know, we cannot possibly know either.

Comment: Possibly, by "Feature" here we mean [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(machine_learning)). However, considering what has been given in question, the answer would be fully solving a problem, which I consider to be "too broad" for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well if that is the definition of the feature in the question, then the teacher should've mentioned what it is, unless he is the machine learning II teacher...

Comment: QUESTION edited